# Create and associate with Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

Can I create and associate related model in-line? For example

Let be table **countries** with *ids* and *names*. For instance `171 | Poland`.

Table **addresses** has column *country_id* as **foreign key**, but ***not null*** and columns such as city, street and others.

In **AdressModel**, *$fillable* property is set as well.

And now, to create new Address from request, I know three ways to do it.

1. Add the **'country_id'** to **AddresseModel** $fillable property, and then Country::create($request->address);
2. Use `new Address()` and then assign fields to matching object's properties. Finally `save()`;
3. Allow **'country_id'** to be *nullable*, make `Country::create($request->address)` and the call associate() on given relation method, country() in that case.

Is there a way to do that inline without nullable(), something like:

```
$country = Country::find($request->country_id);
$address = Address::create($request->address)->country()->associate($country)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```php
$country = Country::find($request->country_id);
$address = $country->addresses()->create([
    'city' => 'Barcelona',
    ...
]);
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right! But what if I have model with two relations, for example *UserModel* has `address_id` and `company_id`, both foreign keys *aren't nullable* and related models are creating with *UserModel* at once? Is it too much for Eloquent maybe?

Comment: Actually, I have never run into this scenario, so I don't really know if Eloquent can handle this. I guess I would take a different approach here: I would create first the company and the address and, after that, I would create the user (just like method 1 in your example)